# Push objects from array into specific fields of another array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I've a method to get the data (days, month) from the current week.
I want to push this data to an array in the specific object field and later loop through this array to display it.

I really have no idea how to do this.

```html
<div v-for="day in days" :key="day.index">
  <p>{{ day.month }}</p>
  <p>{{ day.numberDay }}</p>
  <p>{{ day.textDay }}</p>
</div>
```

```js
  data() {
    return {
      // days: [{ textDay: "", numberDay: "", month: "" }]
      days: []
      
    }
  },

  methods: {
    getCurrentWeek() {
      const currentDate = moment();

      const weekStart = currentDate.clone().startOf('isoWeek');

      const days = [];

      for (let i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
        days.push({ textDay: moment(weekStart).add(i, 'days').format("dddd") });
        days.push({ numberDay: moment(weekStart).add(i, 'days').format("Do") });
        days.push({ month: moment(weekStart).add(i, 'days').format("MMMM") });
      }

    this.days = days
    }
  }
```

Comment: I do not recommend using Moment.js in 2022.

Comment: Hi kissu and thanks! What do you recommend instead?

Comment: Anything from here: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/recommendations/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be pushing values in days array like this.
Please revert, if this solves your problem.

```
    for (let i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
days.push({textDay: moment(weekStart).add(i, 'days').format("dddd"), numberDay: moment(weekStart).add(i, 'days').format("Do"), month: moment(weekStart).add(i, 'days').format("MMMM")});
}
```